# error: parsererror using Jquery, AJAx and JSON

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

could you help me with this please:

I'm working on a search page in php and try to retrieve just one specific record from a mysql table via Jquery-AJAX-JSON, the inconvenient is that I don't rceive any data from process.php(the file that query the database) to show in buscador.php instead of that I got an error in firebug like in the image

[image: error]

Could you please tell me what is my error, this is my form buscador.php

```
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
<meta name="tipo_contenido"  content="text/html;" http-equiv="content-type" charset="utf-8">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="content/estilos.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<title>BUSCADOR</title>
</head>
<form method="post" id="form_id" action="process2.php">
<fieldset>
<legend> Buscador Asincrono</legend>
 <p>ID a buscar: <input type="text" name="ID_name" id="ID_id"/><div id="estado_id"></div></p>
 <p><input type="submit" id="submit_id" value="Buscar"/></p>
 <img src="imagenes/cargando.gif" id="LoadingImage"  style="display:none" align="center"/>
 <div id="ajax_id"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
 <div id="msg">
<table id="infoemp" border="1" style="display:none" align="center">
<thead>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Cargo</th>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</html>
```

this is my jquery2.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form_id").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    preparar();
     if(validaForm()){  
       requestInfo();
    } 
  });
});

function preparar(){
    $("#submit_id").hide();
    $("#ajax_id").html("");
    $("#LoadingImage").show();
    $("#ajax_id").html("<div class='cargando'> realizando busqueda</div>");
}

function validaForm(){
        var id_val = $("input#ID_id").val().trim(); 
        if((id_val=="") || id_val.replace(/s+/,'') == ''){
            alert("Favor ingrese el ID");
            $("input#ID_id").addClass("posicionamiento");
            $("#ajax_id").html("<div class='error'>Debe especificar el nombre</div>");
            return false;
        }else{  
        $("input#ID_id").removeClass("posicionamiento");
        $("#div_id").empty();
        }
        return true;
}   

function requestInfo(){

    var url = $("#form_id").attr('action'); 
    var data = $("#form_id").serialize();   
    var type = $("#form_id").attr('method');

    $.ajax({
    url:url,          
    data:data,       
    type:type,      
    cache: false,  
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    dataType: 'json', 
    encode: true,
 })   

.done(function(data) { 
if(data.success == "true"){
$("#ajax_id").html(""); 
//$("#ajax_id").html("<div class='cargando'>" +data.users.status+ "</div>");
$("#ajax_id").html("<div class='cargando'>" +data.info.total+ "</div>");
//$("#ajax_id").html(data.users.status).addClass("cargando");   
$("#submit_id").show();
$("#LoadingImage").fadeOut();   
$("#infoemp").show();

var output = "<h2>" +data.total+ " empleado encontrado</h2>";

  output += '<ul>';
  output += '<li>' + data.Nombre + ': ' + data.cargo + "</li>";
  output += '</ul>';
  $("#ajax_id").html(output);

} else {  $("#ajax_id").html(data.success).addClass("cargando"); }
})

.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    $("#LoadingImage").fadeOut();
    $("#ajax_id").html(textStatus).addClass("cargando");
  if ( console && console.log ) {
       console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  textStatus);
     }
    });

    }
```

and this is my process2.php file

```
<?php

$bd = "ejemplo";
$server ="localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";

$errors = array();  // array para almacenar los errores
$data   = array();  // array para devolver info

if (isset($_POST['Submit']) && isset($_POST['ID_name'])) {
    $valor = filter_var($_POST['ID_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if ($valor == null)
        $errors['ID_name'] = 'Debe especificar el ID de busqueda.';
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;

    } else {
         obtenerEmpleados($valor);
}

function obtenerEmpleados( $valor ) {

    $mysqli = @mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $bd);
    if( ! $mysqli ) die( "Error de conexion ".mysqli_connect_error() );

    if(!$prepared_st = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM empleado_php WHERE ID = ?")){
    die("Error creando la consulta"); 
    }   

    if(!$prepared_st->bind_param("s",$valor)){ 
    die("Error vinculando parametro");
    }

    if(!$prepared_st->execute()){
    die("Fallo en la ejecución");
    }

    $result = $prepared_st->get_result(); 
    if($result->num_rows>0){     
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['total'] = sprintf("Se han encontrado %d usuarios", $result->num_rows);

    $fila = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $data['Nombre'] = $fila['Nombre'];
    $data['cargo'] =  $fila['cargo'] 
    }

    $prepared_st->close();
    $mysqli->close(); 

    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parsererror` message comes from the JSON parser, which has found an error in the string it is trying to parse. Probably, the string is not JSON at all.

You haven't posted the string that is actually being received by the browser, but this is what I suspect is happening:

You have defined your database connection variables in the main body of your PHP code, but attempt use them in a function here:

```
function obtenerEmpleados( $valor ) {
    $mysqli = @mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $bd);
    if( ! $mysqli ) die( "Error de conexion ".mysqli_connect_error() );
```

The variables are out of scope, so your connection fails and your script returns the string `Error de conexion...`. This is not JSON, but your Javascript code has been told to expect it as JSON, so you see a parse error in your browser.

You need either to pass your connection variables into your function as arguments, or declare them as global.

Comment: thanks, according to your suggestion I created a message inside an array in order to notify any error, for example $var[error]="couldn't bind the parameter" and then send that array with json_encode, the parsererror has disappeared but now all I got is undefined in the values I want to show, do you have any idea ?

Comment: At a guess, you haven't actually fixed the root cause of the problem. You seem now to be returning the error message as a JSON object but nothing else has changed.